# How to check if something is an .net exception or the custom exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Like in the question. I want to check if something on the collection of exceptions is my custom exception or is it the Exception class given by the .Net framework. Thnaks in advance for your help. \

Please note:

I don't know what is the class name of my custom exception it could be called exceptionA, exceptionB or for example xyzException

I have code like this:

```cs
    public IEnumerable<Type> GetClassHierarchy(Type type)   
    {
        if (type == null) yield break;

        Type typeInHierarchy = type;

        do
        {
            yield return typeInHierarchy;
            typeInHierarchy = typeInHierarchy.BaseType;
        }
        while (typeInHierarchy != null && !typeInHierarchy.IsInterface);
    }

    public string GetException(System.Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (ex.InnerException == null)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }

        var exceptionHerarchy = GetClassHierarchy(ex.GetType());


        var isMyException = exceptionHerarchy.Any(t => t != typeof(System.Exception));

        if (isMyException)
        {
            return string.Format("{0};{1}", ex.Message, GetException(ex.InnerException));
        }
        else
        {
            return GetException(ex.InnerException);
        }

    }
```

var isMyException = exceptionHerarchy.Any(t => t != typeof(System.Exception)); this is alays returning true because there is this type on the list probably

Comment: Maybe you could check exception type's namespace.

Comment: Why? That probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that exactly?

Comment: You probably mean that you don't _which_ one instead of that you _never_ know what there names are.

Comment: Like I said eralier, I want to detect if something is cyustom exception show the messages seperated by ";" or if it's the system type of en exception I'm getting the messege from the deepest one. I already have some code I will paste it maybe...

Comment: Okay, you've showed a bunch of code, but what do you want it to do?  Note that currently `isAxaException` will always be false; you *know* that `System.Exception` will be in the type hierarchy no matter what.

Comment: @Silvermind sorry my enlgish is not so good and I was typing fast,  Servy yes I know it will be but there will be also my custom exceptions. I want to detect which of them are my custom ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very simple:

```
var t = myException.GetType().FullName;
bool isSystemException = (t.StartsWith("System."));
```

Exception types in the .NET Framework are all in `System` or one of its subnamespaces.

*EDIT:* To make this slightly prettier, create an extension function to the `Exception` class:

```
public static bool IsSystemException(this Exception exception)
{
    return (exception.GetType().FullName.StartsWith("System."));
}
```

Comment: This assumes nobody ever creates a custom exception in the system namespace...that assumption may not hold true.

Comment: Basically go through all exceptions in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @RoyDictus But you can write programs that will work regardless by not using fragile programs that *rely* on intelligent users.  Thinking everyone in the world isn't stupid is going to result in disappointment.

Comment: I will try this solution, but I agree witn Sriram Sakthivel it's not the prettiest one

Comment: @Rafal_Koscinski: There's a way to make it slightly (although not much) prettier, and that is by adding an extension function, say, `IsSystemException()`, to the Exception class, with the code above in it. That hides the inner workings and makes the code that uses that function cleaner.

Comment: @Roy Dictus: yeah but this works for me :) I know it is ugly but it works. I will ask the people responsible for the decision if it's ok. THANK's TO EVERYONE for the help :) I did not know that it could such simple... :)

Answer (score 3):

Double reconsider why do you want to do it. And then use one of the solutions below.

**Better**

Derive all custom exceptions from one base class exception provided by you and catch it in `try-catch` block.

**Worse**

Dynamically check some information about exception using Reflection, like its assembly:

```
ex.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your Exception class extend from a custom base class.

```
        class MyBaseEception : Exception
        {
        }

        class MyCustomException : MyBaseException {}

        try
        {
        }
        catch (MyBaseException customException) {....}
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
```

Although one wonders why you want to do this.

Comment: we have some nested exceptions and in our application we get the error that doesn't tell anything. But underneath there is a real message deep down. The application has multiple eceptions like the .NEt exceptions and custom ones.

Comment: Then utilize inheritance to have a property containing information you want on the base exception class. Or just reconsider your application design/use a logger. ANY exception at run-time is bad.

Comment: Rather than an if, can't you just have multiple catch statements?

Comment: @Rafal_Koscinski also nested exceptions aren't a problem as long as the exception hierarchy for your custom exceptions starts with MyBaseException as a base.

Comment: I make a base exception for every solution I create. The name for it is the namespace of the solution. That way, you can catch the custom base exception to see if an error is coming from your solution, team, department, what have you.

Answer (score 0):

Heres my 2 pence...

```
try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name != "My.Own.Namespace")
            {
                // this is a .net exception?
            }
        }
```

Comment: Namespace != assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Why have custom exceptions if you're unsure when they would fire?  IME, custom exceptions are typically used around business logic when you want to handle a specific case.  Otherwise rely on the framework.  In terms of the code, stack your custom exceptions first, then have a catch all in case the custom exception does not fire.

```
try
{
    //do something 
}
catch (MyCustomException ex)
{
    //log, continue, throw, etc
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //log, continue, throw, etc
}
```